# How to implement header like Google Play press

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-design

How to implement header like Google Play press?
How to implement an animated image in the background, which scrolls along with the content?
Google Play Press screen1: [full header](https://yadi.sk/i/actpExK0i8udh)
Google Play Press screen2: [minimized header](https://yadi.sk/i/udqqjzq9i8ukG)

My code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.inthecheesefactory.lab.designlibrary.activity.CodeLabActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:background="#123456"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/nav_header_bg"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#234123"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:tabContentStart="0dp"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollViewContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="800dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_icon_tint_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_text_color"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_items" />
```

Comment: There is a nice tut : http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en

Comment: mehdok, I've already used this source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use library https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager/

This is what you need:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I searched